# I have strings , and a list of sentences i need to seperate out those sentences in the list that contain the strings

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, substring

Can any one suggest me the best algorithm in this case . or best techniques for such operations.i know how to do it the basic way by comparing both string to all sentences . but is there a better way.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question properly, help me understand. You have a list of strings and list of sentences and you want to separate out sentences in the list that contain the strings. Please explain using an example, might be helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: @surajs1n i want a sorting algorithm that filters the best results when searching for a keyword among bunch of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KMP algorithm for pattern searching. Search each of your string (pattern) in the list of sentences 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/

If there are `m` sentences
sentence length is `n` (longest)
and there are `k` number of pattern to be searched . The worst case complexity would be `O(m*n*k)`